# Can someone explain this solution to a basic circuit analysis question?

Tags: circuit-analysis

**Problem:**

[image: Problem]

**Solution:**

**[image: Solution]**

I would have labeled my reference marks for Rx's voltage with the positive to the left of it and the negative to the right of it since the current is flowing from left to right, so applying KVL with this convention would have made Vx positive. However,the solution labeled as Vx negative, why?

Comment: Comment from @jonk actually answers "Can someone explain this solution to a basic circuit analysis question?" Misprint.

Answer (score 1):

The solution starts off with a mistake. i_x is not 0.5 ma.: it can't possibly be
so. The problem was probably meant to have the arrow pointing to the left or
have i_x be -0.5 ma. Knowing that, the problem is a simple Ohm's law problem. 
The voltage across R is 9 volts, so the voltage across the right 10k resistor is
6 volts, and the current through it is 0.6 ma. going right to left. That current
splits with 0.5 ma going to the left 10k resistor and 0.1 ma going down through
R. R is 90k.

Comment: Checked, either the current has the wrong direction (sign), giving Rx as a negative resistance of -476.2 Ohms, or if the current is in the other direction, the unknown resistance is 90 kOhms

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured out why my assumption was incorrect. My assumption would have been correct if the given potential differences were voltage sources. However, they are not so they need to be treated as loads.

Comment: Assuming the voltage measurements are accurate, they got the sign of \$i_x\$ wrong. The statement says it is \$500\mu A\$ and provides an arrow for direction. So that completely specifies it. Given the arrow, the actual value must be \$-500\mu A\$. Either the arrow, or the value, is wrongly stated. The two could only co-exist if R were a negative resistance.